# Query returns null If any child table has null record

Tags: sql, postgresql, sqlexception

New to PostgreSQL, getting parent and child table data in a single query. The issue is if any one of the child table has null records, the whole query returns null.

```
SELECT r.resume_id,
       r.resume_name,
       r.updation_date, 
       edu.education_id, 
       edu.title, 
       edu.institute,
       exp.experience_id, 
       exp.designation, 
       exp.company_name, 
       exp.start_date, 
       skill.skill_id, 
       skill.skill_name 
  FROM user_resume r, 
       user_education edu, 
       user_experience exp, 
       user_skill skill 
 WHERE edu.resume_id = r.resume_id AND 
       exp.resume_id = r.resume_id AND 
       skill.resume_id = r.resume_id AND 
       r.resume_id = 1592570
```

Here is my query in this case the given resume has no records in the experience table, in result it returns null, if I remove the join with experience table, then it returns records.

More in resume table, i have these `Boolean` fields also, that are false if child table (`experience, education or skill table`) has no related records.
`education_missing, experience missing, skill missing` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
FROM user_resume r
    ,user_education edu
    ,user_experience exp
    ,user_skill skill
```

[is](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-join.html) left inner join - it is expected behaviour...

```
FROM user_resume r
LEFT OUTER JOIN user_education edu on COLUMNS
LEFT OUTER JOIN user_experience exp on COLUMNS
LEFT OUTER JOIN user_skill skill on COLUMNS
```

instead

Answer (score 0):

This will work. LEFT OUTER JOIN will give you detail from resume table and there will be NULL in the columns from child table.

```
SELECT r.resume_id,
   r.resume_name,
   r.updation_date, 
   edu.education_id, 
   edu.title, 
   edu.institute,
   exp.experience_id, 
   exp.designation, 
   exp.company_name, 
   exp.start_date, 
   skill.skill_id, 
   skill.skill_name 
 FROM user_resume r 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN user_education edu ON r.resume_id = edu.resume_id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN user_experience exp ON r.resume_id = exp.resume_id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN user_skill skill  ON  r.resume_id = skill.resume_id 
 WHERE 
   r.resume_id = 1592570
```